# Make all lines to and from to be red when mouse hover on block in jsplumb

Tags: jsplumb

In my application we have created flow chart using Jsplumb tool with Ext js 4 and in this I have one requirement that when I will mouse-hover over the block then all lines to and from for that block needs to be turn red .[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Gqy.png**strong text**

I attached image for more specify , here if we click on block B then all lines which is connected to other block needs to be turn red.

Can you please provide me proper solution?